Amd apu not being detected CPU: AMD Ryzen™ 5 7600X
before I get started I'm going to go ahead and get this through I am very new to Linux!!!
I was going to do a virtual machine GPU pass-through but then when I ran the Virtual Machine my screen went blank and my APU never kicked in. after restarting I plugged my HDMI cable to my integrated and plugged my second monitor into my graphics card and it was spitting out tons of errors like Ubuntu has experienced an internal problem and all of them were gnome issues after looking at all the detected devices there was nothing that involved my APU
24.04.1 LTS Desktop
fizzy@fizzy-B650-EAGLE-AX:~$ lspci -k | grep -E 'VGA|3D|Display'
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 21 [Radeon RX 6950 XT] (rev c0)
12:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raphael (rev c7V)

Yes i have 2 gpus but my apu is not there
